# Parallel processing on ATmega328

Tags: parallel-processing

I want to implement the ideea of parallel processing , with 3 ATmega328 microcontrollers . The problem will be a trivial one , computing a number's factorial and writing the result on a LCD display. One of the 3 microcontrollers will be the dispatcher , it will receive the problem and will split it into smaller task for the other 2 microcontrollers . Now , my question is , how can I implement the communication between the microcontrollers , what to send from dispatcher ? Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I don't have to much code related to this topic , I want a general answer , what to send from one microcontroller to another ( executable code , just some commands , etc ) ?